# i cant create string array with cursor data in android

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

```
private static final String Memo_Name = "MemoName";
```

.

```
openDB();
            String[] col = new String[] {Memo_Name};
            Cursor c = db.query(Memo_Table, col, null, null, null, null, null);
            String[] result = new String[c.getCount()-1];
                 if(c.moveToFirst()){
                      for (int i = 0; i < c.getCount(); i++){
                          result[i] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Memo_Name));
                          c.moveToNext();
                        }//end of for
                 }
                db.close();
```

**ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException** on this line

result[i] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Memo_Name));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

glad I could help.
just so you could close the question -

remove the " -1 "